# How can I access the installed pod library macro string in UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, sinch, callkit

I installed sinch (working in swift)

inside pod folder "SINAPSEnvironment.h"

```
#ifndef SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic SINAPSEnvironmentProduction
#else
#ifdef DEBUG
#define SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic SINAPSEnvironmentDevelopment
#else
#define SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic SINAPSEnvironmentProduction
#endif  // ifdef DEBUG
#endif  // ifdef NDEBUG
#endif  // ifndef SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic
```

In UIViewcontroller.swift I am using

```
push = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic)
push?.delegate = self
push?.registerUserNotificationSettings()
push?.setDesiredPushType(SINPushTypeVoIP)
```

In here "SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic" getting error. (Use of unresolved identifier 'SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic')

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: SinchRTC this pod ?

Answer (score 1):

inside the ViewController on the top, 
make sure that you added the module

```
import //Module name
```

under  UIKit, 
in your case i think its this pod,

> SinchRTC

just make sure its imported, and how to use it reading the documentation [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SinchRTC)